# int as pointer to a file containing a video stream

Tags: c#, pointers

Maybe it is just too late or I am just standing in my own way, but I am struggeling to understand the following line from [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7388/A-Simple-C-Wrapper-for-the-AviFile-Library?fid=62163&fr=376&df=90&mpp=25&prof=False&sort=Position&view=Normal&spc=Relaxed#xx0xx).

There is a function called `Videostream`, which is to create a Videostream(obviously).
The constuctor of `Videostream` looks the following:

```
public VideoStream(int aviFile,              //pointer to the file object
                   bool writeCompressed, 
                   double frameRate, 
                   Bitmap firstFrame)
```

Where `aviFile` declared is as the file that contains the (empty) stream.
Now, How can I create a pointer to a file with an empty stream as an **int**?

I mean, it would be possible just to pass it as a string, but I have literally no idea how to pass it as an int.

Comment: Can you shed more light about how this pointer to the file is obtained and why is it stored in an `int`?

Comment: Exaclty that is my Question. I didn't wrote the code, I am just using it. And I have no idea why it is stored as an int, I thought somebody else knew it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Avi.AVIFileOpen()` opens a file by string and returns an `int` (sort of file handle) which you probably can use as parameter to the `VideoStream` constructor.

The signature of `AVIFileOpen` looks like this:

```
public static extern int AVIFileOpen(
  ref int ppfile,
  String szFile,
  int uMode,
  int pclsidHandler);
```

Comment: Do you have a good source/doku where `ppfile`,`szFile`,`uMode` and `pclsidHandler` stand for? What values should be entered there?

Comment: I have no idea, I only looked at that project for 1 minute. But is contains sample code, no?

Comment: No, not at all, at least no reviewable code. But I found another solution by using the `AviManager`-class, which turned out quite good. nevertheless, thanks.